# Android - robotium test cases hang at certain test

Tags: android, android-activity, junit4, robotium

I have an app to be tested in automation. When click it, it will first launch activity A (Welcome page activity), After some seconds, it will go to start activity B.

My automation test can be execute separately. But when I run them together, it will hang in certain test(I am sure it is not because of circulation).

Here is my code:

```
public class OSNCommonLib extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

    public  final static String mainActiviy = "XXXX.LoginActivity";//Activity A
    static {

            try {

                launchActivityClass = Class.forName(mainActiviy); 

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);

            }

        }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public OSNCommonLib() {
            super(launchActivityClass);
        }
    @Override 
            public  void setUp() throws Exception {     

                    super.setUp();
                    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());   

            }

        @Override
        public void tearDown() throws Exception
        {

            try {

                solo.finishOpenedActivities();


            } catch (Throwable e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            super.tearDown();

        }
}
```

Here is my test Class extend the class above

```
public class ConversationTest extends OSNCommonLib{
public ConversationTest() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        super();

    }
public void test01()
    {
        XXXX
        //solo.goBack();
    }
    public void test02()
    {
        XXXX
        //solo.goBack();
    }
    public void test03()
    {
        XXXX
        //solo.goBack();
    }

}
```

It will always hang on the **third** test.
My question is: Shall I use solo.goBack()? In fact, I am confused about whether to use solo.goBack because I have teardown. I think solo.finishOpenedActivities() will work.
But the result seems strange.
Could anyone help me about this?
Besides, as I have two activity A and B, does this problem caused by it?

Thanks a lot!